# How to target .NET Core with a classical VS csproj?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

For reasons I cannot explain on SO we cannot update one of our projects to the new VS2017 csproj format, it has to stay "classical". We still want the project to target .NET Core 2.1. How to do that?

If I change the TargetFrameworkVersion from "v4.5.2" to "netcoreapp2.1" the project can't be loaded anymore.

Comment: AFAIK, it can't be done. you need to use the new csproj format in order to use the newer, simpler format.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cant be done. VS reads the project files differently, and as such requires a different format. If there is a technical reason why you cant upgrade the solution, you need to have a think about how important that technical reason is for stopping the project from evolving. Failing all of that - can the code be split out into a new project that "can" be upgraded?